# Can I use a SVG as the poster for HTML 5 video?

Tags: html, video, svg, html5-video

I'm building a streaming video experience (web based, not native) for desktop & mobile.

The `<video>` element supports a thumbnail / poster image (if omitted, it uses the first frame of video. Since I can't use `src set` or whatever to ensure a reasonably sized image is used, can I use an SVG instead (assuming appropriate aspect ratio)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<video controls width="640" height="480" poster="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/bd/Test.svg">
    <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4">
</video>
```

I believe that this configuration does work.